# How to create a column with the maximum number in each row of another column in PySpark?

Tags: pyspark

I have a PySpark dataframe, each row of the column 'TAGID_LIST' is a set of numbers such as {426,427,428,430,432,433,434,437,439,447,448,450,453,460,469,469,469,469}, but I only want to keep the maximum number in each set, 469 for this row. I tried to create a new column with:

```
wechat_userinfo.withColumn('TAG', f.when(wechat_userinfo['TAGID_LIST'] != 'null', max(wechat_userinfo['TAGID_LIST'])).otherwise('null'))
```

but got TypeError: Column is not iterable.

How do I correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the column for which you want to retrieve the max value is an array, you can use the `array_max` function:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

new_df = wechat_userinfo.withColumn("TAG", F.array_max(F.col("TAGID_LIST")))
```

To illustrate with an example,

```
df = spark.createDataFrame( [(1, [1, 772, 3, 4]), (2, [5, 6, 44, 8, 9])], ('a','d'))

df2 = df.withColumn("maxd", F.array_max(F.col("d")))

df2.show()

+---+----------------+----+
|  a|               d|maxd|
+---+----------------+----+
|  1|  [1, 772, 3, 4]| 772|
|  2|[5, 6, 44, 8, 9]|  44|
+---+----------------+----+
```

In your particular case, the column in question is not an array of numbers but a string, formatted as comma-separated numbers surrounded by `{` and `}`.  What I'd suggest is turning your string into an array and then operate on that array as described above.  You can use the `regexp_replace` function to quickly remove the brackets, and then `split()` the comma-separated string into an array. It would look like this:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame( [(1, "{1,2,3,4}"), (2, "{5,6,7,8}")], ('a','d'))

df2 = df
    .withColumn("as_str", F.regexp_replace( F.col("d") , '^\{|\}?', '' ) )
    .withColumn("as_arr", F.split( F.col("as_str"), ",").cast("array<long>"))
    .withColumn("maxd", F.array_max(F.col("as_arr"))).drop("as_str") 

df2.show()

+---+---------+------------+----+
|  a|        d|      as_arr|maxd|
+---+---------+------------+----+
|  1|{1,2,3,4}|[1, 2, 3, 4]|   4|
|  2|{5,6,7,8}|[5, 6, 7, 8]|   8|
+---+---------+------------+----+
```

Comment: It's not an array... It's a string of numbers enclosed by {}... I tried to convert it to an array with "f.array_max(f.array(wechat_userinfo['TAGID_LIST']))". It didn't throw an error but it only returned the entire string as the maximum value... How should I convert it to an array?

Comment: I also tried "f.array_max(wechat_userinfo['TAGID_LIST'].replace('{', '').replace('}', '').split(','))", and it threw 'Column' object is not callable.

Comment: Ok, that wasn't 100% clear in your question.  I have updated the answer to address your situation.